# showCallout without tapping -iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, annotations, ios6, mkannotationview

I have several annotation pins on the map. I would like to show info on the one of the default pin by triggered showCallout I know how to implement by tapped, but I dont know without tapping on the annotation, how could it show showCallout? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
id<MKAnnotation> myPin = [mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0];
[mapView selectAnnotation:myPin animated:YES];
```